# Angular UI Bootstrap Typeahead directive creates a different DOM element for every instance

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use the  [Angular UI Bootstrap Typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) directive in a few tables. These tables could have 0 to thousands of entries in them and when I attach the `typeahead` directive to each `<input>` in my table rows, it creates a DOM element for each one!

If I inspect the DOM after the page loads, I can see hundreds of `<!-- ngIf: isOpen() -->` on the body of my HTML. The thing is, all of these typeaheads use the same source list to supply the typeahead with it's data, so techincally I should only need 1 typeahead element that is just re-used on each input in my tables.

Currently, I do not see a configuration attribute on the typeahead documentation that allows us to create 1 shared typeahead element.  Is there any way to easily get this functionality to work without altering the angular bootstrap javascript myself or without building the typeahead directive from scratch?

**EDIT**

To make things even worst, I have pagination on my tables and if you change between "pages" of the tables, the directive re-creates more `<!-- ngIf: isOpen() -->` for every new instance of that page. Therefore, if the table starts out with 100 items per page out of 10 pages, if the user clicks on each page of the pagination at a time, they will end up with 1000 `<!-- ngIf: isOpen() -->` on the page.

Comment: So by changing it so we don't append the typeahead to the body, now it will not create more typeahead elements with each pagination page change, but there is still a unique typeahead for each row in the table and any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Implement some kind of view/edit state transition on the cell that contains the `typeahead` directive.

Use something like an `ng-if="row.isEditing"` on the input with the `typeahead` directive. As-is, your table is going to create a DOM element for every row unless you tell it not to. When you click into the cell to edit, then change the edit mode state, and the DOM element for the typeahead will be loaded on-demand.

This plunker is (somewhat) like the approach I have in mind, but it implements a whole edit row instead: http://plnkr.co/edit/ivJQ0C

Notice in that example that the DOM element for the edit row does not exist until the condition of the `ng-if` is met.